# Maven: build jar containing specific classes from other sibling modules

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

I have the need to build a jar file, which contains a selection of individual class files from other sibling maven modules.

I've tried using the maven-assembly and the maven-jar-plugin's, but can't seem to come up with a working pom/config.

Could anyone give an example pom.xml (and possible an assembly.xml) which would do this?

Any help would be appreciated.